# Laravel 4 redirect (homepage)

Tags: laravel-4

I have finished my website with laravel 4. I deploy it to my server and find out that I need to go to : www.example.com/public/ to access the homepage.

How to do the setup to access the home page directly when typing the url : www.example.com? I did a index.php with a header Location etc etc but Laravel didnt like it^^

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your virtual host to point to `/public` rather than the root of the Laravel (`/`) installation

You can usually do this if you have access to your web host's control panel.

Answer (score 0):

actually, it's better practice and laravel intends to, if you change your directory structure.

let's say, your current dir structure is like this

```
./
   www/
       app/
       public/
       bootstrap/
       vendor/
```

change it :

```
./
   app/
   www/
   bootstrap/
   vendor/
```

see? move up `app`, `bootstrap`, `vendor` etc. then rename `public` folder to (in this case:) `www` or whatever directory used by server doc root.

Or, if you really don't want change directory structure, you can simply use this:

```
return Redirect::to('/public');
```